# How can I sort based on descending numbers in a single cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I have values in a cell that look like this:

```
0 AND 
1 AND 
3 AND 
4 AND 
2 OR
```

I want the result to looks like this:

```
0 AND 
1 AND 
2 OR 
3 AND 
4 AND
```

Each value is separated by a line break (char(10)).  How can I run a small script to sort these values?

Thanks.

Comment: Split the string on the Char(10), then sort the array, then use Join() to put it back together.  All three items are easily searchable on Google.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me service.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, yes.  Thanks for the tip.  When I did it your way, it turned out to be super easy!

```
        Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1 + totalVals)).Value = splitVals

            ' SORT ASCENDING BOOLEAN VALUES
            Range("BC2").Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
            With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NEW Format").Sort
                .SetRange Selection
                .Apply
            End With
            Range("BC1").Select
```

I don't need to rejoin at the end.  I need to split out this array and concatenate it with elements of another array.

Thank you!